# Asp XML feed reader

Tags: xml, asp-classic, rss-reader

## What I have so far

I am creating a news feed for my site and I currently have this.

```
<%
TheFeed = "http://feeds.feedburner.com/Actsoft"

Set objXML = Server.CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")

objXML.Async = False
objXML.SetProperty "ServerHTTPRequest", True
objXML.ResolveExternals = True
objXML.ValidateOnParse = True
objXML.Load(TheFeed)

CellCount = 0

If (objXML.parseError.errorCode = 0) Then
   Set objRoot = objXML.documentElement
   If IsObject(objRoot) = False Then
       Response.Write "There was an error retrieving the news feed"
   Else
       Set objItems = objRoot.getElementsByTagName("item")
          If IsObject(objItems) = True Then
              For Each objItem in objItems
                  On Error Resume Next
                  TheTitle =  objItem.selectSingleNode("title").Text
                  TheLink =  objItem.selectSingleNode("link").Text

                  Response.Write "<div class='article'>" &_
                                 "<a href=" & TheLink & ">" & _
                                 "<span>" & TheTitle & "</span>" & _
                                 "</a>" & _
                                 "</div>"
             Next
         End If
     Set objItems = Nothing
   End If
Else
    Response.Write "There was an error retrieving the news feed"
End If
Set objXML = Nothing
%>
```

## What I need out of this

I want to limit the amount of objects that are displayed in my reader.  Right now every article is being displayed, and I want to limit by showing only the first 4.

I am **new to Asp** so I have no idea how to go about doing this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can be done with a counter in the for loop but I would like to use [XPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256115.aspx).
Set the selection language to **XPath**.

```vb
objXML.SetProperty "ServerHTTPRequest", True
objXML.SetProperty "SelectionLanguage", "XPath"
```

Select the elements with

```vb
objXML.selectNodes("//item[position() <= 4]")
```

instead

```vb
objRoot.getElementsByTagName("item")
```

Then, first four will be displayed.
**A suggestion about** `If IsObject(objItems) ... etc` **:**
The methods such like *[getElementsByTagName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms765549%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)*, *[selectNodes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms754523%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)* returns a collection of elements that have the specified name / expression.
If no nodes match the name / expression, returns an empty list / collection and it does not cause an error when you try to iterate it natively (*For Each*).

But, some selection methods returns a node object only (*[selectSingleNode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms757846%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), [getNamedItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms767592%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)*). If no node match, returns `Nothing`.
The problem is that, `Nothing` is an object too. Therefore `IsObject(Nothing)` returns always true. 
In such cases, you can handle like following.

```vb
'On Error Resume Next
Set TheTitle = objItem.selectSingleNode("title")
Set TheLink = objItem.selectSingleNode("link")

If TheTitle Is Nothing Then TheTitle = "" Else TheTitle = TheTitle.Text
If TheLink Is Nothing Then TheLink = "" Else TheLink = TheLink.Text
```

Comment: This has to be the best answer I have ever received on Stack Overflow. Thank you so much.